# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I'm a J2EE noob (.Net stack) and am at my wits end trying to get a basic tutorial off the ground. I'm using Eclipse with Tomcat 8.5 set up.

I keep seeing this error in the console when trying to launch my application...

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09:39:42,442 ERROR ContextLoader:351 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.<clinit>(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.getResourcePatternResolver(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.<init>(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 13 more
Sep 09, 2016 9:39:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.<clinit>(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.getResourcePatternResolver(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.<init>(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 13 more
```

My config files look like this...

applicationContext.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="datasource-config.xml" />
    <import resource="webflow-config.xml" />        
</beans>
```

datasource-config.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="user" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
    </bean>         

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

webflow-config.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd">

    <bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener">
        <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener" />
            <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>            

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />
    <faces:resources />

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

</beans>
```

Stuff like this reminds me why I despise declarative programming so much.

My pom XMLlooks like this...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.j2eeapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>j2eeapplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>J2EE Application</name>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing logger dependencies in your project build path.
If you are using common logger then add below dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

if you are using logback, slf4j then exclude common loggings and use below dependencies:

```
    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>

 </dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>     
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I'll add my POM.xml

Comment: If I add the exclusions XML element I get a malformed POM error

Comment: can u post your pom.xml file

Comment: and where does shows the malformed POM error

Comment: I'm not clear where the exclusions bit is supposed to go. If I put it under 'dependencies' I get an error - If I put it under 'project' I get an error. From other examples it seems that it needs to sit under an existing dependency but I don't know where.

Comment: use exclusion like this in your pom.xml                                      <dependency>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>

   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>  
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory**

Error is about missing dependency, commons-logging jar is missing in your classpath. Your POM.xml may be missing

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and you may want to exclude spring webflow transitive dependent on 'commons-logging'

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem

Comment: what do you get after adding the dependency?

Comment: Exactly the same error - I'm not sure I need commons-logging as I've got a log4j dependency - I've added the POM above.

Comment: could possible spring webflow overriding your commons logging i guess. add the exclusion in addition  to  above

Comment: Nope - same error again

Comment: check if your tomcat lib has commons-logging in lib folder

Comment: I'm adding all of the Maven dependencies to the server